# Get SOAPMessage from org.apache.camel.Exchange

Tags: java, soap, cxf, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I need to get the SOAP message from exchange object I receive in my spring bean.

I have a camel route, which routes from service endpoint to my java bean. Java Bean and Camel route declared in spring looks like this:

```
<bean id="processor" class="com.groupgti.esb.camel.wrapper.gradireland.userregistration.UserRegistrationProcessor">

<camel:route id="route">
    <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:myListenerEndpoint?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&amp;synchronous=true" />
    <camel:bean ref="processor" />
    <camel:to uri="cxf:bean:myTargetEndpoint"/>
</camel:route>
```

In my java bean I receive the exchange object:

```
@Override
public SOAPMessage processMessage(Exchange exchange) {
    Object object = exchange.getIn().getHeaders().get("CamelCxfMessage");
    LOGGER.debug("Object: " + object);
    SOAPMessage message = null;

    if (object instanceof SOAPMessage) {
        message = (SOAPMessage) object;
        LOGGER.debug("Got message: " + message);
    }

    LOGGER.debug("Sending message...");
    return message;
}
```

The problem is that I can not get the SOAP message out of the exchange. I camel web site, [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html) I found that I have to use this to get the SOAP message:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = (SOAPMessage) exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class).get(0);
```

But his gives me `NullPointerException` somewhere deep in exchange.

I have tried to debug and see the object tree. I found that I can get the message like this:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = (SOAPMessage) exchange.getIn().getHeaders().get("CamelCxfMessage");
```

But this gives me this exception:

```
org.apache.camel.ExpectedBodyTypeException: Could not extract IN message body as type: interface javax.xml.transform.Source body is: null
```

I am stuck here. Maybe someone know where can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAYLOAD mode is not quite the easy way, maybe you should try the POJO mode for CXF, and get rid of SoapMessage. You will have to declare a POJO with JAXB annotations, like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Registration {

    private Long roomNumber;
    ...

}
```

This will allow you to work directly on the Registration class in your processors (which I assume is your final goal).

```
Registration registration = exchange.getIn().getBody(Registration.class);
```

If you persist with PAYLOAD mode, note that you can write

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, SOAPMessage.class);
```

Comment: One more thing. Registration is just one operation. How am I supposed to know what operation I get in mu processMessage method? Is there anyway I can check it in camel?